# How to get primary domain name in azure active directory using azure cli

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-cli

Is there a way to get the primary domain name using [Azure Cli az ad command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad?view=azure-cli-latest)

[image: Azure Ad primary domain]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct command to get **Primary domain** using Azure CLI.

Alternatively, you can make use of either **[Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)** or **PowerShell** like below:

In my Azure Portal, my **Primary domain** looks like this:

[image]

Using **Microsoft Graph Explorer**, you can run query like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains?$select=id
```

**Response:**

[image]

> **You can run the above query in **Azure CLI** using **`az rest`** method like below:**

```bash
az rest --method get --url 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains?$select=id'
```

**Response:**

[image]

Using **PowerShell**, you can run command like below:

```
Connect-AzureAD 
Get-AzureADDomain
```

**Response:**

[image]

**References:**

[List domains - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/domain-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Get-AzureADDomain (AzureAD) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddomain?view=azureadps-2.0)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
((Get-AzureADTenantDetail).verifieddomains |where {$_._default -eq $true}).name
```